# spark-submit error while running kafka spark streaming jar

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-submit, spark-streaming-kafka

I am trying to run my kafka spark streaming application using spark submit. Its java maven project and I have created a fat jar using assembly plugin. The same jar I am trying to execute using spark submit but it fails with below error. My pom.xml dependencies are as below.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>consumer</groupId>
  <artifactId>consumer</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  
   <properties>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>

<build>
  <plugins>
    
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.1</version>
    </plugin>
    
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
     <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>
                     consumer.consumer
                    </mainClass>
                </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
</plugins> 
</build>
  
 <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.6</version>
   </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.influxdb/influxdb-client-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.influxdb</groupId>
    <artifactId>influxdb-client-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.influxdb/influxdb-client-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.influxdb</groupId>
    <artifactId>influxdb-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.12</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>  
</project>
```

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/Consumer
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies$.Subscribe(ConsumerStrategy.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe(ConsumerStrategy.scala)
    at consumer.consumer.consume(consumer.java:156)
    at consumer.consumer.main(consumer.java:80)
```

1. Tried giving all dependencies in classpath using --jars in spark submit. But no luck.
2. Tried lowering versions for spark and kafka and scala. But still getting same error.
3. Tried using same scala version for kafka and scala but no luck.
4. Tried using the same versions as Kafka and Scala installation jars, but couldn't fix it.

I am using spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7 and kafka_2.13-2.6.0 on standalone machine.
Anything I am missing here? I tried implementing answers from similar questions as well but its still erroring out. Appreciate any help with this.Thanks!

Comment: Have you added the required jars in the classpath? or have you created fat jar with all the required dependencies ?

Comment: 1) Spark core and streaming need a provided scope added to them 2) You should try removing kafka-clients dependency 3) any reason you're not using Structured Streaming? 4) Did you open the built jar file and find the mentioned class that cannot be found?

Comment: @koiralo i have created fat jar with all required dependencies

Comment: @prikene did you check the required class are present in the jar file?

Comment: @koiralo I extracted the fat jar and do see the .class files for spark, kafka, kafka-client, scala, etc.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I did try with provided scope but it didn't work. No specific reason for not using structured streaming. As a beginner I just tried direct approach first. 

The same fat jar works fine when running via command promt using java -jar filename.jar command. so it does have all the dependent jars in it, right? It just cant work with spark-submit.

Comment: Provided scope wasn't to fix the error here, but it's still necessary to not get conflicting Spark versions when you submit (which should be done using spark-submit)... Other than that, can you show the full POM file?

Comment: Do you get the same error running the example? https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaDirectKafkaWordCount.java#L48

Comment: @prikene : were you able to solve the problem. I am also facing the same issue

Comment: @pradoshnair yes! its version issue after trying different version, it worked for me. Here is my new POM.xml dependencies looks like :-                                                          spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12 <version>2.4.6</version>
spark-streaming_2.12<version>2.4.6</version>
 kafka-clients<version>2.6.0</version>
spark-core_2.12<version>2.4.6</version>
scala-library<version>2.12.11</version>